# Using inner or outer join based on input parameter - without using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

It is possible to condition a join to outer or inner according to the value of a parameter without using dynamic sql?

- I mean, if a parameter(filter value) is given then the query must
  return exactly matching records (or 0 records) - acting as **inner join**
- If this filter is not provided then it is needed to return all
  records - acting as an **outer join**

Comment: Maybe.  Depends on which table the filter applies to.  If your query is an outer join but you apply a predicate to the table you're outer joining to, that effectively turns the query into an inner join.  The same thing does not apply, however, to the driving table.

Comment: The case is that the condition applies for the outer joining table, so how to get 0 records when we filter by one non-existing value for this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filter is on the table you're outer joining to

```
select some_columns
  from left l
       left outer join right r
         on( l.right_id = r.right_id )
 where r.filter_column = p_some_parameter
    or p_some_parameter is null
```

would seem to be all you need.  If `p_some_parameter` is specified, the predicate effectively turns the `outer join` into an `inner join`.  If `p_some_parameter` is not specified, the query remains an `outer join`.